# How do I save/edit Data on multiple tabs when I have multiple tables?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two tables "users" and "notes". Both share the same key "user_id".

I have the Magento forms up and working at this point..., I'm just not sure how to make it so when I save the notes part, it updates to the notes table. For editAction, I was thinking of using a Join in say my editAction to pull all of the information using

```
$user = getResourceModel()
```

Then Having

```
Mage::register('current_custuser', $user);
```

so my block could access all of that users information.

To clarify:

I have two tabs (more later). I have separate tables (users and notes). I want to be able to save the information from Notes tab to notes table, and users tab to users tab. Do I need to use joins for this? How would I go about getting this done? Do I use Joins?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question. Do you have two separated models for the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your save action you can get the data coming from the forms and then instantiate both models in separated variables to set the info and then save each model with the data coming from the tabs.
Something like:

```
$modelA = Mage::getModel('modelA');
$modelB = Mage::getModel('modelB');

$modelA->setData($dataA);
$modelB->setData($dataB);

$modelA->save();
$modelB->save();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!